# Buying + activating Google Fi in the US but not a US resident?

Tags: usa, cellphones, data-plans

I'm currently on a 3 week trip in California, visiting mostly in and around the major cities and I've been looking into buying a Google Fi 'simple unlimited' plan for a month for my data/calling/texting while staying here. I was planning to go pick up a SIM card from one of the stores here and then buy the plan online, but I'm now a bit confused if i even can purchase a Google Fi plan when I'm not a US citizen. For clarification, I'm in the US on vacation and will only be in Cali for the month, but considering i don't have a US address or credit/debit card (not sure if the card being US is necessary) I'm wondering if it's even possible to use Google Fi while I'm here for the month? The posts online vary depending on the year, so I'm wondering if I can actually purchase a Fi SIM card in a store, and in the online sign-up use a billing address of a friend living here, or my current hotel or something like that. Or if that won't work? Also curious as to whether the entire thing will work with my phone (Samsung Galaxy S10+) if it's manufactured and bought in Europe? Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Is it possible to sign up for Google Fi as a tourist in the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106390/is-it-possible-to-sign-up-for-google-fi-as-a-tourist-in-the-us)

Comment: Yes I've read that post but it seemed quite dated as it was 4 years ago and the most up to date response is 3 years ago, from other sources on the web it implies you can't use a european phone, and the shipping to the address part is seemingly only relevant for getting the actual sim package to you when in my case im buying it from a store

Comment: My answer was written earlier this year. See https://support.google.com/fi/answer/6224695?hl=en for supported phones.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that Google Fi's [Terms of Service](https://fi.google.com/about/tos/) says this:

> You must be qualified. This offer is only available to qualified US residents over 18 years of age. We may make this offer available to you only after we have reviewed your credit information and determined that you have qualified for this offer. To determine if you qualify for the Phone Subscription, you may be required to provide information such as your name, address, and your Social Security number, and we may share that information with a third party to check your credit information, including your credit score...

We are all here aware that some users have successfully signed up for and/or continued to use Google Fi in violation of the Terms of Service. Still...

*Caveat emptor*.

Comment: The **Terms of Service** also says: 'You must have an active Google Account to use the Services, **and we will associate your Google Fi account with your Google Account**.'. For existing non-US Google Accounts, it will be clear that the OP is only visiting the US.

Comment: Downvoted because this clause is never actually enforced in practice.

Comment: @JonathanReez Could be so. There were repeated mentions of revocations in 2020 and earlier, but I find none since. Still, the ToS provides Google an out if they wish it.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I bought a Google Fi sim in 2018 that’s still successfully in use abroad. Even if they do deactivate it eventually you can just shrug and get another sim or two to replace it. I’d even buy a few sims in advance to throw out and swap eventually.